Sort ValidationMessageStore by display order attribute
I'm using Blazor Web App and have a component that uses EditForm and ValidationSummary.  All works well, except I want to sort the error messages by the order specified in my model. Here's my simpified-for-example model:
public class ContactModel
{
  [Display(Order = 1)]
  public int ContactID { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Display(Order = 2)]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [Display(Order = 3)]
  public string MiddleName { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Display(Order = 4)]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

I'm adding a custom validation (example only) that if a middle name is entered, it must be at least 5 characters.
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_model.MiddleName) && _model.MiddleName.Length < 5)
{
    messageStore?.Add(() => _model.MiddleName, "Middle name must be at leaset 5 characters.");
}
_editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();

If I leave the first name blank and only enter two characters in the middle name, I get the two validation errors in the ValidationSummary... BUT... through some other testing I have found that the custom errors are displayed before that annotated errors.  This makes the order:
'Middle Name' must be at least 5 characters
'First Name' is required

I want to display the messages in the order defined in the model's:
[Display(Order = XX)]

attributes.  How can I do this?

You could try implement validation attribute
Above5Attribute.cs
    public class Above5Attribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if ((value != null)&&(value.ToString().Length < 5))
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Middle name must be at leaset 5 characters.");
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

Then use the attribute on "MiddleName"
...
        [Display(Order = 3)]
        [Above5]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
...

Test
<EditForm  Model="Contact" FormName="form1" OnInvalidSubmit="test">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div>ID:<InputNumber @bind-Value="Contact.ContactID"></InputNumber></div>
    <div>First:<InputText @bind-Value="Contact.FirstName"></InputText></div>
    <div>Middle:<InputText @bind-Value="Contact.MiddleName"></InputText></div>
    <div>Last<InputText @bind-Value="Contact.LastName"></InputText></div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</EditForm>
@code{
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public ContactModel Contact { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized() => Contact ??= new();
    private void test(){}
}



First, thank you for a quick reply.  This will only work for the MiddleName property of this small example model.  I was looking for a more generic approach as some models have dozens of properties.  I already have the "Order" in the Display attribute.  I'm looking for a way to sort the messages by that.
